# Scrolling in a different layer in Chrome using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, scroll, webdriver, instagram

I am writing a code in python using the module selenium, and I want to scroll on a list that is on a different layer in the same window. Imagine you go to Instagram, click on followers, and then wish to scroll down to the bottom so that selenium can make a list of all the users who follow that page.

My problem is my code scrolls on the layer below, which is the wall of the user.

```
def readingFollowers(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/followers')]")\
        .click()    

    sleep(2.5)

    scroll_box = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]')

    # Get scroll height
    last_height = self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollHeight", scroll_box)

    while True:
        # Scroll down to bottom
        self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);", scroll_box)

        # Wait to load page
        sleep(1)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollHeight", scroll_box)
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
```

I have used Google Chrome, and the inspect element would be the same on all the systems (most probably).

For complete code, you can comment on me, in case you are not able to understand the problem. I can give you the code required to recreate the situation for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are already logged-in on the IG account.

```
def readingFollowers(self):
    #click followers
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="-nal3 "]').click()
    time.sleep(5)

    pop_up = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="isgrP"]')
    height = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollHeight", pop_up)
    initial_height = height

    #default follower count is 12
    followers_count = 12
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollBy(0,arguments[1])", pop_up, initial_height)
        time.sleep(5)

        #count loaded followers
        count = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="PZuss"]/li')) 
        if count == followers_count:
            break
        followers_count = count

        #add height because the list is expanding
        initial_height+=initial_height
```

It took me some time but it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works after some changes. I understood my error.